# Finding Variance from a Joint CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So the equation is $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=x^{2}y+xy^{2}-y^{3},\quad{}0<y<x<1$

And I need to find the $Var(y)$

I am unsure of how to solve this from a joint CDF, at first I didn't notice it was a CDF and just tried to find the marginal PDFs, but I don't think I can do that in this case. What exactly do I need to do in order to be able to get the marginal PDFs as I don't think I can just take the derivative with respect to $x$ and call that the PDF.

Comment: You can get the joint PDF by $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x\; \partial y}F(x,y)$ and then find the marginal PDFs.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you! I'm a little ashamed I didn't think to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Given the CDF $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = x^2 y+x y^2-y^3$, then the density is

$$f(x,y) = \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x\, \partial y}F_{X,Y}(x,y) =
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left\{  
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 x+2 y & 0<y<x<1 \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}
\right.
 \\
\end{array}$$

The marginal density, $f_y(y)$, is

$$f_y(y) = \int_y^1 (2 x+2 y) \, dx = 2 y+1-3 y^2$$.

Then $E(Y)$ is

$$E(Y) = \int_0^1 y f_y(y)dy = \int_0^1 y(2 y+1-3 y^2)dy=\frac{5}{12}$$,

and

$$E(Y^2) =  \int_0^1 y^2 f_y(y)dy = \int_0^1 y^2(2 y+1-3 y^2)dy=\frac{7}{30}$$.

Thus, the variance, $Var(Y)$ can be computed by

$$Var(Y) = E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2 = \frac{7}{30} - \left(\frac{5}{12}\right)^2 = \frac{43}{720}$$